# Regex for international numbers - no space

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I am trying to create a regEx that will have an optional '+' as the first character and then after accept all digits, making sure no spaces are allowed.

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work :

```
new RegExp(/^\+?\d $/);
```

Comment: You could pre-parse `telnumber.replace(/\s/g, "")` before testing then it wont matter if people use spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
new RegExp(/^\+?\d+$/);
```

Replace space in your regex with `+`. `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Comment: add multiline modifier `m` if necessary.